# RegExp function with long text

Tags: regex, angular, web

I have a book with footnotes which I want to display.
I put the footnotes in their place inside curly brackets.

In order to retrieve the comments and display them in a different window,
I wrote the following class in Angular 2:

```
export class BookreaderComponent implements OnInit {

async comments() {
    var regexp = new RegExp('\{(\s*?.*?)*?\}');
    var array= await regexp.exec(this.book);
    console.log(array);
  }

  constructor(public appServices: AppServices, private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  book: string;
  Name: string;
  json: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.Name = params['name'];
      this.http.get("./assets/" + params['url'])
        .map(ref => {
          return ref;
        }).subscribe(async ref => {
          this.book = ref.text();
          await this.comments();
        });
    });

  }
```

The class calls the `comments` function, which calls a regex function on a large amount of text, that contains a lot of curly-bracketed text.
The problem is that the regex function takes a **very** long time to load (I waited and waited, and it didn't load), and meanwhile the whole page is stuck.

Is there a way to speed this up, or maybe break this up into smaller chunks?
Or maybe I should try a different way to display these footnotes?

Comment: How big is the text and how many comments (approx)?

Comment: It looks like your regex is really bad, why not use `var regexp = /{([^}]*)}/;`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This regex doesn't find anything. It returns null.

Comment: @RichardMatsen About 40000 words, 296 comments.

Comment: [It works well](https://regex101.com/r/kfFuHS/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Then something is wrong with my code maybe. What is it?

Comment: If you provided reproducible code, someone could help you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My text is Right to left, maybe that is the problem. Although I tested it in regex101.com and it found all the comments.
I provided my code in my question.

Comment: Leaving aside the question of whether the regex expression is optimal, I tried it in [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/) and it returns 664 matches in 5.9ms for a 5500 size text.

Comment: I suspect the async / await might be influencing things. Can you please re-post the question, leaving off the regex tag.

Comment: @RichardMatsen async / await doesn't influence. Tried it. Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47562164/regexp-function-with-long-text-in-angular

Comment: Cheers. Interesting, async/await isn't _usually_ used when using observables. I'll take a look.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I'm playing with the text, and it looks like it's because that it's right to left and it gets mixed up with the curly braces. What can I do?