# RegExp function with long text in Angular

Tags: regex, angular

I have a book with footnotes which I want to display.
I put the footnotes in their place inside curly brackets.

In order to retrieve the comments and display them in a different window, I wrote the following class in Angular 2:

```
export class BookreaderComponent implements OnInit {

comments() {
    var regexp = new RegExp('\{(\s*?.*?)*?\}');
    var array= regexp.exec(this.book);
    console.log(array);
  }

  constructor(public appServices: AppServices, private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  book: string;
  Name: string;
  json: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.Name = params['name'];
      this.http.get("./assets/" + params['url'])
        .map(ref => {
          return ref;
        }).subscribe(ref => {
          this.book = ref.text();
          this.comments();
        });
    });

  }
```

The class calls the `comments` function, which calls a regex function on a large amount of text, that contains a lot of curly-bracketed text. The problem is that the regex function takes a very long time to load (I waited and waited, and it didn't load), and meanwhile the whole page is stuck.

Is there a way to speed this up, or maybe break this up into smaller chunks? Or maybe I should try a different way to display these footnotes?

Comment: From previous comment, 'it looks like it's because that it's right to left and it gets mixed up with the curly braces' - I'm not familiar with right-to-left text, but will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a test [Angular Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XLoIeJq7iMwLVFaY9SDi?p=preview) which omits the `http.get`. The speed of the regex looks fine without the observable in the picture.

I had a look at the right-to-left aspect, but can't see how it affects the regex. In any case, I left the regex expression as-is, with `?` as I noticed someone posted that RTL needs lazy evaluation.

Also, most RTL language discussions seem to focus on CSS tags, so I'm wondering if there could be any effect due to RTL. After all, it's still a string? Could you please supply a short example of RTL so I can clarify my thinking.

**Note**

`var array= regexp.exec(this.book);` only returns the first match. To use this syntax, you need to loop until no more matches. So instead I used `this.book.match(re)` which is faster.

```js
const getMockBook = () => {
  const line = 'Here is some text with a {comment} in it';
  const lineCount = 2000;
  const book = (new Array(lineCount)).join(line);
  return book;
}

const comments1 = (book) => {
  const start = new Date();
  const regexp = new RegExp('\{(\s*?.*?)*?\}', 'g');
  const array= regexp.exec(book);
  return `elapsed: ${(new Date()) - start}, size: ${book.length}, matches: ${array.length}`
}

const comments2 = (book) => {
  const start = new Date();
  const re = /{(\s*?.*?)*?}/g
  const array= book.match(re);
  return `elapsed: ${(new Date()) - start}, size: ${book.length}, matches: ${array.length}`
}

const book = getMockBook();
console.log(comments1(book));
console.log(comments2(book));
```

Comment: It worked!!!
Probably because I didn't use match, so it returned only one or two values. 
Wow, thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem. So much for 'duplicate question'. That really is a curse.

Comment: Yup :). Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Should add back the regex tag now :).